# What is the theoretical reason/advantage to the limits of integration of a definite integral being either "lower" or "upper"?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, notation

Suppose that, instead of the standard notation for the definite integral of a function of one variable:

$$\int_a^b  f(x)\,dx= -\int_b^a  f(x)\,dx$$

we used something like:

$$(a,b)\int  f(x)\,dx$$for $b>a$, and $(a,b)$ is the open interval from $a$ to $b$, wherein the limits of integration have no inherent sense of ordering.

Would we be losing anything with this new notation? The reason I'm asking is because I can't see a logical reason for the requirement that we specify not only the domain of integration, but also the "order" in which the function must be integrated. Shouldn't specifying a function and a domain of integration be sufficient information for the unequivocal definition of the number corresponding to the integral of that function over such a domain? It seems as if adding the extra step of saying what is the "lower" bound and the "upper" bound of integration adds no useful information to the process, just confusion.

Comment: Sounds like you want some foundations of measure theory and integration over sets.

Comment: Why do you think it would only add confusion?  Orientation is an important concept.

Comment: @user10354138 Because I can't see what we gain from introducing the concept of orientation to the definite integral. Also, what does orientation mean when we think of higher-dimensional domains of integration?

Comment: @SeanRoberson Do you have any references you could recommend?

Comment: You want to talk about orientation? Integration on manifolds answers that. Hubbard and Hubbard's text on vector calculus gets you started.